# Decomposing continuous functions in separable subspaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X$ be a compact space and $G$ a separable and metrisable locally compact group acting on $C(X)$. Is it true that one can write $C(X)=\cup_i A_i$ where each $A_i$ is a separable, closed and G-invariant vector subspace of $C(X)$?

Comment: You must actually have more conditions on $A_i$ in mind - as stated this is trivial: Let $A_0=C(X)$ and $A_i=0$ for $i>0$. (Also: Do you really mean the union, as opposed to some sort of sum?)

Comment: But is $C(X)$ always separable?

Comment: Yes, $C(X)$ is separable. Say $(x_n)$ is a countable dense subset of $X$ and let $f_x(x)=d(x,x_n)$. Stone-Weierstrass shows that the linear combinations of finite products of the $f_n$ are dense in $C(X)$. Hence the rational linear combinations of finite products of the $f_n$ are dense. (Here I'm counting $1$ as a finite product of the $f_n$, namely the product of none of them - if you don't like that add it in.)

Comment: But why does the countable dense subset of $X$ exist? $X$ doesn't has to be separable, or? $X$ is just a compact space. Only $G$ is separable. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Sorry, I thought $X$ was a compact metric space. Of course if $C(X)$ is not separable then the decomposition you ask about cannot exist, since it _implies_ that $C(X)$ is separable...

Comment: In [this](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjE5cLGi7LYAhUCElAKHULIAu8QFggqMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbremy.perso.math.cnrs.fr%2Fsmf_sec_18_04.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1BukCuayeEU6BuHFw_NkZu) paper of Benoist on page 36, $(2')\Rightarrow (1)$ this is claimed and I wonder how to proof it. In my opinion there are no more assumptions than I gave. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I assumed the letter $i$ meant you wanted a countable union. The language in the paper "the $F_\alpha$ are the..." sounds like he's considering _all_ such $F$, hence perhaps not countably many. If we allow an uncountable union what you want is staggeringly trivial: For $f\in C(X)$ let $S(f)$ be the closed span of the orbit of $f$ under $G$. Then $C(X)=\bigcup_{f\in C(X)}S(f)$.

Comment: Ah that sounds reasonable. One last question: Is it clear to you that the dual spaces of the $S(f)$ are metrisable? I know that the closed unit ball and therefore **bounded** subsets of $F^*$ are metrisable in the weak-*-topology if $F$ is separable. (This is also mentioned in the paper)